# TextField - behave like PowerPoint

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

I have a Dynamic TextField created with ActionScript (multiline, wordwrap & autosize=true).

While running the SWF, if you click into the TextField you get an arrow "move" cursor, then you can double-click to put it into Edit mode to select text. I want it to work like PowerPoint - if you click into the box you'll always get a flashing cursor with the ability to select/insert text, and you can click on the borders to drag, or the corners to resize.

I tried adding the focusIn event `textField.stage.focus = this.textField` but this didn't seem to do anything. When you click into the textField, I basically want it to act as though you followed with a double-click (Edit mode) without actually having to do the double-click.

Bonus: and instead of a 2nd double-click returning you to the Move mode (or whatever it's called) I want to select all text.

TL;DR: Is there some property of a Dynamic TextField that I can get/set to see if I'm in Edit or Move mode?

Answer (score 0):

the `TextField` class is not made for what you want.

What you need to do is to create a subclass of `Sprite`. Let's call it `SuperDuperTextField`. You'll have to add all the interactivity logic to `SuperDuperTextField`. That `SuperDuperTextField` in turn contains a `TextField` for the text displaying and editing functionality.

while not in editing mode, you may wanna set both `selectable` on the `TextField` and `mouseChildren` on `SuperDuperTextField` to `false` for `MouseEvent`s to work correctly.

To switch to edit mode, you'll need to set the focus and probably also the carret position.

hope that helps.